# How to convert flash with dynamic data into AVI video

Tags: flash, actionscript, image, audio, slideshow

hy,

after i upload some images and one mp3 files on my site it will make a slideshow (.avi file)!
but nothing fancy, only a simple slideshow!

i want to make a stereotyped in flash to load images and mp3 file and make a nice slideshow with some effects!

the problem is... how i can save the swf file? (later to convert .swf file to .avi or .mpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a third party screen capture or video screen recording program for best results.